# regex delete everything before match (All line above)

Tags: regex

i have a html file like:

```
Line1: i want
Line2: to delete
Line3: every line and
Line4: a word boundary before my match like 27.02.2015
Line5: i want to kepp all following lines
```

I use a regex that only find everything in line 4 until the date and everything in line 3.
But i want a regex that find everything until the date. How can i do this?

```
.*?\n.*(?=\d\d\.\d\d\.\d\d\d\d)
```

dosen´t work

Comment: Do you *need* to use a regex for this? It would be much easier to write a parser that accumulates all content until a line contains a date. This is also much more robust.

Comment: Try to add the DOTALL flag to your regex, so that `.` metachar matches new lines as well.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using something like so: `.*?.*(?=\d\d\.\d\d\.\d\d\d\d)/s`. The `/s` flag will ensure that the `.` also considers new line characters.

Your expression can be further reduced (clutter-wise) to something like so: `.*?.*(?=\d{2}\.\d{2}\.\d{4})/s`.

An example of the expression is available [here](https://regex101.com/r/iL5lN8/1).